# Trouble with AngularJS controller & service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code for a small toy angular app

```
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
myApp.factory("Items", function()
{
    var items = {};
    items.query = function()
    {
        return
        [
            {
                title: "Mary had a little lamb",
                price: 2.5, 
            },
            {
                title: "My Experiments with Truth",
                price: 6.25, 
            },
            {
                title: "Indian Summer",
                price: 5.75, 
            },
        ];
    };
    return items;
});
function ItemsViewCtrl($scope, Items)
{
    $scope.items = Items.query();
    $scope.numberOfItems = function()
    {
        window.alert("We have "+$scope.items.length+" with us");
    };
}
```

So, we have a small module, a service and a controller! All good to go!
But the problem is the array **items** is invisible or undefined in the template (that is of course adored by the ng-controller directive).

I even tried creating the controller by calling module.controller(), that did not work as well. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the oppening bracket in the same line as the return statement, i.e.:

```
return [    // <---------- HERE
    {
            title: "Mary had a little lamb",
            ...
```

Otherwise Javascript thinks you are returning nothing! See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HG7Ek/

Comment: (I thought to warn you not to bang your head, curse the JS designers etc :)

Comment: nah! but now I'm going to have an inconsistency in code wrt {} & [] -> the old style wars :P